# Emden–Fowler equation how to solve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve the equation
$$\frac{y''}{y'}=\frac{\alpha}{r y^2}$$, 
which is of the form of the Emden–Fowler equation.

I found a solution in chapter 2.5.2.5 of Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations, Chapman
& Hall/CRC, however i don't understand how to derive it. I need this understanding because i get this equation from differentiating another one, and so i have to impose a constrain on the initial conditions.

The solution is apparently given by, 
$$ r =\pm \exp\left [\left (\int\text{d}\tau \tau^{-3/2}(2\tau^{1/2} - 2 \tau^{-1/2} +C_1)^{-1}\right) +C_2\right ]\,, \tau=\frac{1}{\alpha y^2}$$
So my question is how to derive this result from the equation. Help much appreciated.

[UPDATE: I solved] I simply noticed that,
$$r y'' = \alpha \left(-\frac{1}{y}\right )'\implies \int\text{d}r \,r  y'' = (ry' - y)\Big|_{y_0,r_0}^{y,r} = -\frac{1}{y}\Big|_{y_0}^y$$
integrating once more yields to the desired result.

Comment: Does $'$ mean $d/dr$?

Comment: @RichardMartin yes :)

Comment: With Maple: $y \left( t \right) ={\frac {\alpha}{c_{{1}}r} \left( {\rm W} \left({
\frac {1}{\alpha}{{\rm e}^{{\frac {r \left( t+c_{{2}} \right) {c_{{1}}
}^{2}-\alpha}{\alpha}}}}}\right)+1 \right) }
$ were $W$ is LambertW function.

Comment: I know what is the solution, i want to understand how it is derived.

Comment: From what you've said, the substitution $u=1/\alpha y^2$ should assist. Then get a DE for $u$. But when I tried it, I couldn't make it work.

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the solution if you wish.